# Is it possible to have an expression with the "int -> (int -> int) = <fun>" type?

Tags: ocaml

For `(int -> int) -> int = <fun>` the corresponding expression can be `fun x -> (x 1) + 1`.
Is it possible to have an expression with `int -> (int -> int) = <fun>` type? If not then why?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `int -> (int -> int) = <fun>` is not a type, only the `int -> (int -> int)` part is. The `= <fun>` part is just how a toplevel prints the "value" of a function. For example, after evaluating `1 + 1;;` utop will print `- : int = 2`, where `int` is the type of the expression and the part after `=` is its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an expression with `int -> (int -> int)` type?

Because `->` is right-associative, the type `int -> (int -> int)` = `int -> int -> int`, although the parenthesis is implied. So the function you are looking for is a simple curried function that takes two arguments, e.g.

```
let f x y = x + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You just have to return a function as a value. For example:

```
let f j = fun i -> j + i;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>

f 1;;
- : int -> int = <fun>

(f 1) 2;;
- : int = 3
```

Comment: Not related question, however, do utop and toplevel are not supposed to put parentheses in this case as they do after evaluation of `fun x -> (x 1) + 1`?

Comment: @AlexanderRevyakin The toplevel uses the rule that arrow (`->`) in types  associates to the right, and economize on unnecessary parentheses.